# Is it okay to solicit bug reports?

Tags: ios, debugging, hig

I've noticed that Instagram and some other apps allow users to report problems but don't actually let people report "bugs".  Since I guess the premise of the Apple review process is they catch all bugs and there are no bugs in IOS apps, it makes sense that they do not use the word.

However, is Apple likely to reject the app if you use the word "bugs"?

Coming from a web background where it is okay to launch with a beta, I would like to be honest with users rather than politically correct if that is possible.

The reason I want to let them report bugs is not so much to catch them as we hope to launch bug-free but if anyone has a problem let them report it rather than write a bad review.

Would appreciate any guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: O think you want to use TestFlight during your beta.

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple review guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/);

> **2. Functionality**
>
> 2.2 Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

I don't think this means that they have a filter on the word 'bug'. You may find some bug tracking apps available on the app store where they used the word so rejection it not a given, just because of a `report bugs` section in your app.

But at the time of an Apple review, if they find any bug, they will reject the app so that you may fix it. So you need to be very sharp at it that your app should not have any permanent bug or issue.

For confirmation you may contact App Developer support at https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid using *bug*, *beta* or similar words. The phrase *Bug report* gives users the impression that your app has known issues. I would recommend **Send feedback** or **Contact developer**.

The [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality) does not allow you to submit *beta* apps.

> **2.9**
>   Apps that are "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected.
>   Beta Apps may only be submitted through TestFlight and must follow the
>   TestFlight guidelines

Similarly, you should not leave known issues present in your app. If you already know the issues, you need to fix them before you submit the app.

For example, when I wrote *Please reboot the app if it freezes* in the description, it was rejected.